# Building compiled sagemath script

Tags: cx-freeze, sage

I am trying to compile a sagemath script using cx_Freeze. (I want to use this as the back-end of a web-based AJAX homology calculator.) Is this going to be possible?

I was able to install cx_freeze inside of sage by doing something like:

`sage -pip install ~/Desktop/cx_Freeze-5.1.1`

(I had to download the package manually to avoid some SSL errors)

When I'm ready to compile I use this setup script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

includes = ["sage.all"]

setup(name = "c1homology" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
      executables = [Executable("c1homology.sage")],
      options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes}}
      )
```

Then I compile like this:
`sage c1homologysetup.py build`

and the build fails with a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" after seeming to  import the same thing again again and again. I assume this is because I'm listing sage.all as an include, while building it inside sage, and this leads to some recursive importing.

If I remove `sage.all` from the includes, then it compiles fine, but when I run the executable it doesn't recognize any of the sage commands. Specifically I see `NameError: name 'vector' is not defined`. (vector is the first actual sage command that I use in my .sage file)

Any advice? Or is there a better way for me to do this all? I can just run the sage script without compiling, but it takes forever to load all the sage libraries- I'm hoping that compiling will make it a lot faster. (The actual computation being done by the script is pretty quick by itself.)

I'm using MacOS 10.11.6, Sage 8.7.

Comment: Does it help if you build with `sage --python c1homologysetup.py build`?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri thanks for the idea- seems to have no effect either way

Comment: I know this isn't what you are asking, but when you say "AJAX calculator" I wonder whether trying to use/fork the [Sage cell server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org) would be a better fit for your needs - or perhaps the backend for [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org).

Comment: Also, as a side note, beta versions of Sage now will use Python 3 by default, so you could use cxfreeze 6, I guess.  But I don't know if Sage is "Python" enough to use this utility, I'm not familiar with it, but Sage has a lot of other stuff in it as well.

Comment: @kcrisman thanks I will check out Sage cell server- this looks like it might work for me.